# C# Generic Interfaces Design & Performance

Tags: c#, .net, generics, boxing

I have a basic question regarding generic interfaces.

**Case 1:**

```
public interface IDataProcesser
{
    TOut Process<Tin,TOut>(Tin input);
}
```

**Case 2:**

```
public interface IDataProcesser<Tin,TOut>
{
    TOut Process(Tin input);
}
```

Does Case 1 result in Boxing/UnBoxing ? Is it less performant compared to Case 2. Are there any guildelines while designing generic interfaces ?

Thank you,
Ravi

Comment: It widely depends on what are real types of those `Tin` and `TOut` will be, and regardless that, just measure with some a profiler.

Comment: It would be interesting to know *why* you think boxing may be involved here. There shouldn't be any *performance* differences between these two approaches, and even if there were, would it be an *important* difference that would affect your systems overall performance?

Comment: [Useful background material](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/). Your question is several stages away from even requiring an answer, and by the time it does you'll have a lot more than just these interfaces.

Comment: [*Boxing is the process of converting a **value type** to the type object..*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing) One of things Generics were created for was to aid with avoiding boxing.

Comment: No Boxing/UnBoxing will occurr because you are specifying the type. I cannot see a lack of performance.

Comment: As to the design question: If your `IDataProcessor` has more than one method, case 2 is likely to be more succinct. If implementations of `IDataProcessor` store any TIn/TOut data, case 2 would be necessary. Other than that it's a toss-up design-wise but case 2 seems cleaner especially when you add constraints to it.

Comment: @IanMercer - unless you want to store, say, a `List<IDataProcessor>` and each processor is going to work with different types, in which case case 1 would be indicated.

Comment: Thank you for all the answers. I think i was a little confused between Type casting and Boxing/UnBoxing.  Now I'm a little clear.I'm aware of the fact that Boxing/Unboxing  involves transition between Stack and Heap and vice versa, while Type casting may or may not. Thanks again

Comment: **Boxing does not necessarily involve moving data from the stack to the heap**. If you believe the falsehood that "value types go on the stack", then you are making decisions on the basis of faulty reasoning.  Suppose you have an `int[]` with a million ints. The stack is only a million bytes, that's a four million byte array; do you suppose that it goes "on the stack" because "ints go on the stack"? Of course not!  It is simply false that value types "go on the stack".  **Variables** go on the stack **when their lifetimes are short**.

Comment: Since the value of a value type by definition *lives directly in its variable*, and we know that the stack is *the short term allocation pool* then we know that *value types go on the stack when the lifetime of the variable is short*. Of course this assumes that the short term allocation pool is implemented with a *stack*. It is not required to be; short term allocations can be enregistered, for example, and registers are not *the stack*. When is a variable short-lived? When it is a temp, local or formal that is not closed over and does not span a coroutine suspension.

Comment: Thanks @EricLippert ,that was valuable .I wasn't aware of this, are there any books that you recommend for better understanding of internals

Comment: For language design, *C# in Depth* is very good; the fourth edition will be out soon.  *Essential C#* is less about the language design and more about how to use it effectively. I edited both. For internals, the annotated CLI reference by Jim Miller is the standard reference. I have never read *CLR via C#* by Richter but I have heard from others that it is very good.  And you could do worse than to read my blog.  I am not writing in it at present but hope to get back into it soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method one is *more performant* than method two ( at least one my laptop - see code below). However, That's not really the important part here.

1. If the generic types `TIn` and `TOut` have some semantic meaning to the interface, or most of the methods on the interface then you should include the generic description on the interface.
2. If only one or a few of the methods defined on the interface is using the generic types, then the generic description should be used on the method(s) instead.

However, as you specifically asked about which was more performance, I typed up some quick code and tested it. To my surprise the the first method was actually more performant.

Method one took 3669 miliseconds to run, while Method 2 took 2715.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Sandbox
{
    public interface IDataProcesser
    {
        TOut Process<TIn, TOut>(TIn input);
    }

    public interface IDataProcesser2<TIn, TOut>
    {
        TOut Process(TIn input);
    }


    class Class1 : IDataProcesser
    {
        public TOut Process<Tin, TOut>(Tin input)
        {
            return default(TOut);
        }
    }

    class Class2 : IDataProcesser2<int, long>
    {
        public long Process(int input)
        {
            return default(long);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        private static int _loopCount = 1000000000;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var warmupEquals = false;
            var equals1 = false;
            var equals2 = false;

            for (long i = 0; i < _loopCount; i++)
            {
                Class1 warmup = new Class1();
                var w1 = warmup.Process<int, long>(default(int)) == 0;
                warmupEquals = w1;
            }

            var sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            for (long i = 0; i < _loopCount; i++)
            {
                Class1 c1 = new Class1();
                var t1 = c1.Process<int, long>(default(int)) == 0;
                if (t1)
                {
                    equals1 = true;
                }
            }

            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Method 1");
            Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

            sw.Restart();
            sw.Start();
            for (long i = 0; i < _loopCount; i++)
            {
                Class2 c2 = new Class2();
                var t2 = c2.Process(default(int)) == 0;
                if (t2)
                {
                    equals2 = true;
                }
            }

            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Method 2");
            Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            Console.WriteLine(warmupEquals);
            Console.WriteLine(equals1);
            Console.WriteLine(equals2);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking time and coding it,really appreciate it . Do you think the performance going to improve for Class2 if you warmitup as well ? Since you warmed up the Class1 ,is the processer going to cache the instructions during warmup ?

Comment: No I dont _think_ it will have an impact. I would be mildly surprised if it made a difference - but you can easily test it but running the code on your own machine. After all - hardware matters :)

Comment: Where in your test did you account for the fact that you are allocating objects and charging the allocation to one time interval, but *deallocating* those objects in possibly a *different* time interval?  There might be zero collections in your first stopwatch interval, and then in the second stopwatch interval, the collector stops the world and collects all the objects allocated in the first interval, throwing off your timings.  Getting a correct attribution of time with a stopwatch is quite tricky.